# Is there a better way to get and display data from a related object aside from creating a dictionary?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have two models with one having a foreign key to the other as such:

**Models:**

```
class WhoAmI(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SolarClient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client_owner = models.ForeignKey(WhoAmI, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='solarclients')
    addr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I am trying to simply display an html table showing each client a salesperson has, with the salesperson listed first with a table of clients below their name.

The only way I could figure out how to do this was to create a dictionary using the code shown below.

```
class Homeowners(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        salespersons = WhoAmI.objects.all() 
        homeowners = SolarClient.objects.all().order_by("client_owner")  #the name 'objects' is the Manager

        rangers = {}
        for e in salespersons:
            k = salespersons.get(id = e.id)
            v = k.solarclients.all()
            rangers[k] = v


        return render(request, 'homeowners.html', {'homeowners': homeowners, 'salespersons': salespersons, 'rangers': rangers })
```

I then iterate over the dictionary using:

```
{% for key, values in rangers.items %}
           ... display salesperson
            {% if values %}
               {% for v in values %}
                .... display clients
               {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            ... display "No Clients"
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  It seems silly to put the data into a dictionary to display it, but after many, many hours of trying different methods, this is the only way I could display the data.

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

views.py

```
class Homeowners(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        salespersons = WhoAmI.objects.all() 
        return render(request, 'homeowners.html', {'salespersons': salespersons })
```

html:

```
{% for sales in salespersons %}
 {% for client in sales.solarclients.all %}
   ------ Print Client
 {% empty %}
    ----  Client not exist
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple and I was just stumbling over myself.  This is exactly what I was looking for!!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice handy template filter called [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) built in Django which does exactly what you're looking for.

```
# views.py
homeowners = SolarClient.objects.all().order_by("client_owner").select_related('client_owner')

return render(request, 'homeowners.html', {'homeowners': homeowners})

# homeowners.html
{% regroup homeowners by client_owner as home_owners_list %}

<ul>
{% for client_owner in home_owners_list %}
    <b>{{ client_owner.grouper }}</b>
    <ul>
        {% for client in client_owner.list %}
          <li>{{ client.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The `select_related` method is just for performance improvement and omitting it wouldn't affect functionality.

Comment: Great alternative!  Thanks for the help and explanation.